# resized view after presenting it modally is not coming in middle position after that. Working on iOS versions < 7.0

Tags: iphone, ios

present view controller modally and resizing the view after that but the resized view is not coming in middle position after that. Working on iOS versions < 7.0

code snippet:

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aViewController];

nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

CGRect rect = MSIPhoneUtils::MainRect([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation);

nav.navigationBarHidden = YES;

[self PresentControllerModally:nav withAnimation:YES];

nav.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake((rect.size.width - 320) / 2,(rect.size.height - 480) / 2, 320, 480);

nav.view.superview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

aViewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake((rect.size.width - 320) / 2,(rect.size.height - 480) / 2, 320, 480);
aViewController.view.superview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Comment: you mean you don't support iOS 7 ?

Comment: I think he means that it worked pre-iOS7 and that iOS7 fakked things up ;) This line of questions is very common these days

Comment: yah pre ios 7 it works .Also i was able to solve that by adding   if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] integerValue] >= 7.0)
        [nav setModalTransitionStyle: UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];

Comment: the problem was with default transition UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical in ios 7 and i was able to solve it by changing the transition to UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve